Starship [WARN] - (starship::utils): Executing command "/Users/username/.rbenv/shims/ruby" timed out
I am using Mac and just moved from OhMyZsh + p10k to starship as i love the promt and autocomplete also simple looks.
Then I completed removed OMZ + p10k and brew installed starship.
After configuartion the starship, it always show below messages, so confused whats going on, I do not want to go back to OMZ + p10K cos the .zshrc file is too "large" not that "straight forward" to me.
Here are the warning messages:
[WARN] - (starship::utils): Executing command "/Users/Username/.rbenv/shims/ruby" timed out.                                                                                    
[WARN] - (starship::utils): You can set command_timeout in your config to a higher value to allow longer-running commands to keep executing.
[WARN] - (starship::utils): Executing command "/usr/local/bin/node" timed out.

terminal starship WARN
My homebrew is under /opt/homebrew not usr/local
Is this the issue?
But if I use the homebrew prefix and set to usr/local, brew list will gone, new list will show, whats going on?
I have tried reinstall starship.

Create a starship.toml file under your home dir (if it does not exist)
Run the following command in your terminal:
starship config command_timeout 1000

or simply open starship.toml in an code editor and add the following line (top of the file)
command_timeout = 1000

ref: https://github.com/starship/starship/issues/5985

Thank you for your answer. Actually I have figured out whats going on.
I migrated from intel Mac to Apple Silicon Mac so the old home brew folders and paths were still there, after I removed all old intel brew folders, I am good to go.

Nice. For me, I am on a Intel Mac, so the solution will work for anyone using an intel mac
